# XCUITest performance result metric has only duration

Tags: xcode, xcuitest

I created a XCUITest für measuring performance almost similar like in this WWDC video:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10077/

With this measure part:

```
 measure (metrics: [XCTOSSignpostMetric.scrollDecelerationMetric]){
     tableView.swipeUp(velocity: .fast)
 }
```

Test is running fine and I am getting a result. But in the Performance Result I see as metric only the selected type *Duration (Scroll Decerelation)*.
There is no dropdown for choosing other types like the *Hitch Time Ratio*. 
In the video the dropdown is shown at 9:05.
What I have to do for getting the other metric options?
My XCode version is 12.3.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue until I tried to do it on device.
Seems like this metric is not available because simulator doesn't have a GPU.

Comment: I can't remember if I tested on device or simulator. Currently I am not working with performance tests. But thanks for the hint!

Comment: Using a real device for performance testing is very imperative of course. However I also noted that I can only get Hitch Time Ratio and such metrics if I use a device that has iOS 17 or a recent iOS 16. It just won't work with iOS 15 or like any early version of iOS 16 like iOS 16.2. With iOS 15 etc devices there is always zero hitches - I believe such metrics aren't just supported yet on those iOS versions and that the zero result is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta use a **real device** to make *Hitch Time Ratio* or other metrics to show up, it can only measure those metrics on an actual device for accurate results.

BTW, this is deprecated:

```
.scrollDecelerationMetric
```

use this instead:

```
 measure(metrics: [XCTOSSignpostMetric.scrollingAndDecelerationMetric], options: measureOptions) {
        list.swipeUp(velocity: .fast)
        stopMeasuring()
        list.swipeDown(velocity: .fast)
    }
```